# How to trigger the cloud function for every object created

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I am using a cloud function with a cloud storage trigger. when the files I am exporting are created in the bucket ( ~ 10k files created) the function works but not for all of the files exported to the bucket. when I export a smaller count of files ( ~2000 ) it works for all files exported to the bucket.

for instance: I have about 10k files that will be exported at once from another tool to the bucket. Once they are uploaded to the bucket the function starts working. the function triggered. After validation, I found that it is not triggered for all files (objects ) exported to the bucket.

My question is:

1. Does the cloud function have limitations on triggers per function?
2. Do I have a problem with my cloud function which may cause it not to run for all files?

I am using 1 gen - 8 gb
size per each files (1 kb : 15 mb)

```
from datetime import date, timedelta
import time
import json
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from time import sleep
import datetime
from google.cloud import bigquery
import os
import re
from google.cloud import storage
from google.api_core.exceptions import NotFound

def deduplicate_columns(columns):
    seen = set()
    for col in columns:
        original_col = col
        counter = 1
        while col.lower() in [s.lower() for s in seen]:  
            col = f"{original_col}{counter}"
            counter += 1
        seen.add(col)
        yield col

def convert_and_deduplicate_column_names(dataframe):
    renamed_cols = dataframe.columns.str.replace(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9]', '_', regex=True)
    deduplicated_cols = list(deduplicate_columns(renamed_cols))
    return dataframe.rename(columns=dict(zip(dataframe.columns, deduplicated_cols)))

def hello_gcs(event, context):
    print('Function triggered by the following event: {}'.format(event))

    bucket_name = event['bucket']
    file_name = event['name']
    print(f"Accessing file: {file_name} in bucket: {bucket_name}")

    client = bigquery.Client(project='xxxxxx')
    storage_client = storage.Client()
    bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)

    event_name = '_'.join(file_name.split("-")[2:-3])
    print(f"Derived event name: {event_name}")

    blobs = [blob for blob in bucket.list_blobs(prefix='') if blob.name == file_name]

    for blob in blobs:
        print(f"Processing blob: {blob.name}")
        table_name = f'{event_name}.aaaaaa'
        try:
            table = client.get_table(table_name)
            existing_schema = {field.name: field.field_type for field in table.schema}
            print(f"Existing schema retrieved for table: {table_name}")
        except NotFound:
            existing_schema = None
            print(f"No existing schema found for table: {table_name}")

        chunk_list = []

        if not blob.name.split("-")[2].isdigit() and (event_name == '_'.join(blob.name.split("-")[2:-3])):
            chunk_iter = pd.read_csv(f"gs://{bucket_name}/{blob.name}", dtype=str, chunksize=10000)
            print(f"Reading data from blob: {blob.name}")

            for chunk in chunk_iter:
                chunk['Brand'] = 'KFC'
                chunk['Country'] = 'UAE'
                chunk['Blob_Name'] = blob.name
                chunk = convert_and_deduplicate_column_names(chunk)
                chunk_list.append(chunk)
                print(f"Processed chunk of data from blob: {blob.name}")

        uri1 = pd.concat(chunk_list, ignore_index=True)
        print(f"Event Name: {event_name}, DataFrame Shape: {uri1.shape}")

        if existing_schema:
            new_schema = []
            for col in uri1.columns:
                if col in existing_schema:
                    new_schema.append(bigquery.SchemaField(col, existing_schema[col]))
                else:
                    new_schema.append(bigquery.SchemaField(col, 'STRING'))
            print(f"Schema prepared for data from blob: {blob.name}")

        if not uri1.empty:
            try:
                uri1.to_gbq(f'{event_name}.aaaaaa', project_id='xxxxxx', if_exists='append', location='US')
                print(f"Data appended to BigQuery successfully from blob: {blob.name}")
                # try:
                #     bucket.delete_blob(blob.name)
                #     print(f"Blob {blob.name} deleted successfully from bucket: {bucket_name}")
                # except Exception as e:
                #     print(f"Error occurred while deleting blob {blob.name} from bucket: {bucket_name}, Error: {e}")
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Error occurred while inserting into BigQuery: {e}")
        else:
            print(f"No data to append from blob: {blob.name}")
    else:
        print("There are no files in the bucket to append")
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "works but not for all of the objects"?  You should explain in detail what specifically is not working the way you expect using a specific example.  We should be able to duplicate the problem using the instructions you provide. Please edit the question to be clear.  I also suggest reviewing this [checklist for asking questions](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/checklist).

Comment: @DougStevenson I have edited it and illustrated what I mean. the function is triggered but not for all files exported to the bucket. and triggered for all files when I use smaller count of files.

Comment: How exactly did you determine that the function was not triggered for all files?  We need to be able to see what you see in order to make sense of this.

Comment: I tested it in 2 ways: 1. After the function was triggered I deleted the files. there were some files that remained in the bucket. 2. without deletion: I pushed the name of the csv file as a column in a table to bigquery. not all of the files were pushed in comparison to the files in the bucket.

the question is do we have any limitations about the total count of files the function will be triggered on in the 9 minutes?

Comment: There's no limits without clear error messages. Your question should focus on the details of what you're doing that are different than what you expect.  Make the assumption that you're doing something wrong, and share with us the details we can use the reproduce the issue.  Please edit the question to be clear - don't leave your debugging details in comments.